# How to match one column in one dataset with either of two columns in another dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

Hi I have two dataframes A and B in R. I want to match the first column of A with the first **or** second column of dataframe B. Because the matched information is stored in the first **or** second column of dataframe B. Do you know how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: First join B on A by the first column, then join B on A by the second column, then select the non NA value. If you provided a **minimal** reproducible example ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)) it would be possible to give more specific help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `sqldf` package has a function `sqldf()` which allows you to run SQL statements on data frames as if they were database tables.

```
install.packages('sqldf')
library(sqldf)
C <- sqldf('select * from A join B on A.id in (B.id1, B.id2)')
```

It can work with inner joins (as above) or left joins. (Right joins and full outer joins are not supported at present.)